# Definition of $C^1_c((a,b);H)$

Tags: functional-analysis

Can I define $C^1_c((a,b);H)$ as space of compactly-supported continuous functions from $[a,b]$ to a Banach space $H$ with compactly supported derivative (that may not be continuous)? So basically I am not saying "continuously differentiable." Would it make sense at all?

Comment: do you mean functions from $(a,b)$ to $H$?

Comment: Ah yeah that's right.

Comment: Do you want weak or strong derivatives (everywhere or almost everywhere)?

Comment: @I want strong derivatives here. Either a.e or e. is fine.

Comment: If you just want to define a *set* of functions, then you already did that in your post. If you want to define a normed space, you should think about the norm. In general, the derivative of a differentiable function may be unbounded, so the supremum of the derivative would not work.